# Parent Iframe URL Query string

Tags: php, javascript

I am having a iframe withing facebook fanpage , the inner iframe is at my server

a link opens the same FanPage again in pop up using `window.open` javascript attaching a query string to it

```
window.open(path,'mywindow','scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,status=no,width=805,height=400');
```

Variable path is same fanpage location with querystring attached to it

```
http://www.facebook.com/pages/mypagename/234234234?sk=app_3457124854683&a=1&b=10000
```

I need to get variables using php
    &a=1&b=100002212364645

Can somebody provide a way to access this in PHP?

Comment: bummer... What could be a way around this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799369/parent-iframe-url-query-string/45630577#45630577

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution i can come up with is(which i actually forgot to Jquery Ajax when i am opening another window(pop up) and perform the action using AJax 
IT WORKS :)

Comment: If this is the solution to your problem, can you please give it the check to close it out?

Answer (score 1):

you may be able to do that using JavaScript using analytic and this would be through referrer. Try using the referrer in php as iframes usually have the parent url as the referrer. But referrers maybe blocked by the user clients.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me you can modify it according to your code.

```
$parent_url = explode('?',$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
$strings = explode('&',$parent_url[1]);
```

$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] it shows the parent URL of the iframe.

You can use $strings as you can.

Hope you like that.